# Exported MOV from Flash Pro with alpha channel doesn't retain transparency

Tags: video

I have an animation I've exported from Flash Pro CS6 as a MOV file with an alpha channel (ignore stage), and I want to do some editing in AE CS6. When I go to import the MOV as Strait-Unmatted, I do get a transparent background, however when I scrub the playhead with transparency grid toggled, [a black background appears behind my animation](http://i1224.photobucket.com/albums/ee378/dcd018/Untitled-1.jpg).

I've tried a number of methods found here and elsewhere on the web including keying out black with luma key, but results were undesirable. Is there a way to get rid of the black behind my animation in AE without effecting the rest of my animation? Or is there an export setting I'm missing in Flash Pro?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as this appears to be a bug, my only suggestion is to export it as a PNG sequence. At my work we always transfer from Flash to AE as a PNG sequence, as we find MOV notoriously unreliable and buggy.

If you need to retain an audio track, try exporting that separately as a WAV or MP3 and placing it on your timeline in AE.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can pick number of colors for output like 256, if the option doesn't have a + symbol after it, it doesn't actually output the matte properly.
Or at least I've had a similar problem when outputting stuff with a trasnparency in AE

Answer (score 1):

In AFX import MOV with options: "Premultiplied - Matted with color" and select black or white color

Answer (score -1):

The only success I've had in AE with regard to rendering a video that has a transparent background is to render it as an FLV file. The other outputs I tried (various MPEGs, MOV, AVI) always pulled a background into the export regardless of the fact I had the transparent background toggle on. (Reminder: also render as RGB+Alpha).

There should be a toggle button to click as to whether or not you want the original video to be in the background of an effect or on top.

With regard to creating a PNG sequence, you'll end up with a PNG image for every frame in your sequence......just sayin' I tried it once.....but only once......I ended up with THOUSANDS of PNG images. I deleted them all and started over because there was no way I was going to assemble all of those. augh!)

Comment: Assembling a PNG sequence in AE is very straightforward, though - it is often the simplest way.